# OpenMP: how to flush pointer target?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, openmp, flush

I’ve just noticed that the following code doesn’t compile in OpenMP (under GCC 4.5.1):

```
struct job {
    unsigned busy_children;
};

job* j = allocateJob(…);
// …

#pragma omp flush(j->busy_children)
```

The compiler complains about the `->` in the argument list to flush, and according to the OpenMP specification it’s right: `flush` expects as arguments a list of “id-expression”s, which basically means only (qualified) IDs are allowed, no expressions.

Furthermore, the spec says this about `flush` and pointers:

> If a pointer is present in the list, the pointer itself is flushed, not the memory block to which the pointer refers.

Of course. However, since OpenMP also doesn’t allow me to *dereference* the pointers I basically cannot flush a pointee (pointer target).

– So what about references? The spec doesn’t mention them but I’m not confident that the following is conformant, and will actually flush the pointee.

```
unsigned& busy_children = j->busy_children;
#pragma omp flush(busy_children)
```

**Is this guaranteed to work?**

If not, **how can I flush a pointee?**

Comment: MSDN says that "A variable specified in a flush directive must not have a reference type". So it is not guaranteed to work on **all** platforms. Not aware about GCC.

Comment: @Kyrill: Ah, f*ck. By the way, the OpenMP spec does definitely **not** mention this, neither 3.0 nor 2.5. And the section numbering differs in the MSDN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flush directive has given the OpenMP ARB a headache for a long time.  So much so, that there has been talk about removing it completely - though that creates other problems.  Using flush(list), is extremely difficult to get correct and even the OpenMP experts have a great deal of trouble getting it correct.  The problem with it, is that the way it is defined it can be moved around in your code by the compiler.  That means that you should stay away from using flush(list).

As for your question about being able to flush a pointee, there is only one way to do that and that is to use flush (without a list).  This will flush your entire thread environment and as such, can not be moved by the compiler.  It seems "heavy handed", but the compilers are actually pretty good about flushing what is necessary when using flush without a list.

Comment: Well, that’s mildly annoying. Thanks for sharing this insight. I’ll swallow the bitter pill then, and flush the whole environment … I *do* need to flush that reference.

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP specification doesn't directly says about the type of a variable, but MSDN says that "A variable specified in a flush directive must not have a reference type". This make me think that this is not guaranteed to work. The `flush` directive with empty variable list should flush all memory so this is what you can safely use.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cannot flush a dereferenced pointer is because flush is only needed for values in hardware registers. There is never any need under OpenMP to flush something that is NOT in a hardware register (for example, in cache or memory), since OpenMP assumes a coherent cache memory that guarantees that all threads will always see the same value when the same address is dereferenced. Hardware protocols guarantee cache coherency, making the multiple local caches behave like one shared global cache.